# How can I avoid "Using selector: EpollSelector" log message in Django?

Tags: django

I upgrade to Django 3.0, and I have been seeing this message in the logs printed to console. How can I avoid it?

```
Using selector: EpollSelector
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This message is from the [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) library that comes with Python 3. You can configure its logging by modifying the [`LOGGING`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGGING) configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'loggers': {
        'asyncio': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
        },
    },
}
```

If you're not using Django, you can use this line of code:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('asyncio').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```